# Having problems in SQLite using Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I had created two lists First List and Second List, and I'm trying to access the Items of both lists but somehow when trying to access the items of the second list, it shows exception main.models.Item.DoesNotExist: Item matching query does not exist.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WTJa.png

Comment: What are the IDs of the 2 item_sets in list2?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and take a look at [ask]. Also [please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I just checked and their ids are 3 and 4 somehow. But how? They are the first two items of a new List.